# xcode не видит библиотеки library not found for -lFMDB

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c

Собственно проблема в том что скачал приложение и не могу собрать его.

есть podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target '<APP>' do
pod 'ZXingObjC'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'OLCOrm'
pod 'FMDB'
end
```

и выдает такие ошибки

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/al/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AkademiaMobile-fktnuhspxwlprrblbzjcanptcruw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FMDB'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/al/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AkademiaMobile-fktnuhspxwlprrblbzjcanptcruw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/al/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AkademiaMobile-fktnuhspxwlprrblbzjcanptcruw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OLCOrm'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/al/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AkademiaMobile-fktnuhspxwlprrblbzjcanptcruw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ZXingObjC'
ld: library not found for -lFMDB
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Что с этим можно сделать что бы проект собрался?

Comment: pod install нормально установился, без ошибок?